# Compilation failing in Visual Studio with template template parameter using non-type parameter pack

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variadic-templates

In Visual Studio I get this compiler error with the below code which I think should compile fine (gcc 11.2 and clang 14.0 compile it). The non-type parameter pack (auto...) means I should be able to pass in a template with any number of non-type template parameters, but the compilation only succeeds when passing in a template that uses a single non-type template parameter.

Is there something I'm missing that will make this work in Visual Studio?

I'm using "/std:c++latest" on Visual Studio 2019, version 16.11.12

error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'testValues::twoParams' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'X'

```
  namespace testValues {
    template<template<auto...> class X>
    struct templatetemplateparam {};

    template<int i>
    struct oneParam {};
    using oneParam_t = templatetemplateparam<oneParam>;

    template<int i, int j>
    struct twoParams {};
    using twoParams_t = templatetemplateparam<twoParams>;
  }
```

The equivalent code with a specific non-type parameter or a type parameter pack does compile, if that's relevant:

```
  namespace testIntValues {
    template<template<int...> class X>
    struct templatetemplateparam {};

    template<int i>
    struct oneParam {};
    using oneParam_t = templatetemplateparam<oneParam>;

    template<int i, int j>
    struct twoParams {};
    using twoParams_t = templatetemplateparam<twoParams>;
  }

  namespace testTypes {
    template<template<typename...> class X>
    struct templatetemplateparam {};

    template<typename>
    struct oneParam {};
    using oneParam_t = templatetemplateparam<oneParam>;

    template<typename, typename>
    struct twoParams {};
    using twoParams_t = templatetemplateparam<twoParams>;
  }
```

Comment: Can you move on to VS 2022?  Microsoft keep plugging away, perhaps they've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I get the same error on VS2022 (version 17.1.4).

Comment: Maybe submit a problem report then?  There's an entry for that in the menu (Help -> Send Feedback).  I believe MS are trying hard to bring MSVC up to speed, in terms of being standards-compliant.

Comment: Yep I've done that but asked the question here in case it's not a bug.

Comment: Please consider putting the link in the **Answer** and accepting it  to change its status to Answered.  So that we can upvote the link and it will help people in the community who have the same issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: I've added the link but will hold off from marking it as the accepted answer until it's confirmed as a bug, otherwise it may just mislead people.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported this to MS at it looks like a bug in Visual Studio to me: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Compilation-error-C3021-when-using-value/10015492